# Принимать запросы только с определенного url-а

Tags: node.js

Пытаюсь решить CORS ошибку в приложении.

Нашел [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031758/node-js-cors-error)  ответ

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

Но как звездочка мне подсказалa этот код принимает запрос из всех url-ов, а мне нужно чтобы принимал только с одного определенного url-а.

Решил добавить вместо звезды локальный url фронта.

```
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000/');
```

Не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может еще кому понадобиться. Решил проблему с добавлением этого кода

```
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000']
}))
```

Другой код соответственно удалил